# How can you calculate where the middle of the screen is using math in python

Tags: python, math

I must've skipped school that day because I cannot remember how to calculate the middle of a square.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Too vague to answer, but something like `width/2` and `height/2`. If that isn't sufficient then you need to explain just how you are representing screens and/or squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to calculate the middle of a square using Python. One way is to find the average of the x and y coordinates of the square's four corners. Another way is to find the point that is equidistant from all four corners of the square.

```py
# method-1
def square_middle(square):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = square
    return ((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2)

# method-2    
def square_middle(square):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = square
    cx = (x1 + x2) / 2
    cy = (y1 + y2) / 2
    return (cx, cy)
```

Comment: The centre! Not the middle!!

Comment: Also, in the code you give, you implement your "method 1" two times. There is no method 2.

Answer (score 0):

frameworks usually report the size of a screen with 2 values or a touple of 2. For example, this is how `pyautogui` reports it:

```
print(pyautogui.size())
Size(width=1728, height=1117)
```

And this is how that framework gets the center for every coordinates tuple:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L579
So you can safely use the example above to get the center of any object on screen, even the screen itself.